# not working addOnSuccessListener for multiple image uploading on firebase. i.e. entering in addOnFailureListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to upload multiple images on firebase storege. but I am not able to upload it.
Below is my code.

---

**AddNewProjectActivity.java "save project method"**

```
private void saveProject() {

        String pro_name, client_name, pro_rec_date, pro_comp_date, total_views, pro_no, arch_no;

        pro_no = binding.projectNo.getText().toString();
        arch_no = binding.architectNumber.getText().toString();
        pro_name = binding.projectName.getText().toString();
        client_name = binding.ClientName.getText().toString();
        pro_comp_date = binding.projectCompleteDate.getText().toString();
        pro_rec_date = binding.projectReceivedDate.getText().toString();
        total_views = binding.totalViewsOfPhotos.getText().toString();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Writing in Database...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Aurum Design");
        progressDialog.show();

        if (!(item.equals("Payment Received or Not?") && item2.equals("Project Status"))) {

            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("project_details");
            StorageReference ImageFolder = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProjectImages");
            final HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            //upload data
            hashMap.put("architect_no", arch_no);
            hashMap.put("client_name", client_name);
            hashMap.put("payment_received", item);
            hashMap.put("project_status", item2);
            hashMap.put("project_complete_date", pro_comp_date);
            hashMap.put("project_name", pro_name);
            hashMap.put("project_no", pro_no);
            hashMap.put("project_received_date", pro_rec_date);
            hashMap.put("total_views_of_photos", total_views);

            //upload Images
            for (upload_count = 0; upload_count < uri.size(); upload_count++) {
                Uri IndividualImage = uri.get(upload_count);
                final StorageReference ImageName = ImageFolder.child("Image" + pro_name + IndividualImage.getLastPathSegment());

                ImageName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        ImageName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String URL = String.valueOf(uri);
                                hashMap.put("image_url"+upload_count,URL);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
            uri.clear();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class));
            activity.finish();

        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "select payment received or not?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "select Project Status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

---

***in the upper code addOnSuccessListener is not working***

---

**entering in addOnFailureListener**

```
ImageName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        ImageName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String URL = String.valueOf(uri);
                                hashMap.put("image_url"+upload_count,URL);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

---

please anyone knows the solution, please tell me. THANKS IN ADVANCE...

Comment: Is the Toast message from `onFailure()` displayed?

Comment: yes.. the toast is displayed

Comment: app is not crashing... but, failure toast is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the error. I forgot to update storage rules to public.**

---

upper code is error free code... so, you can use this code for upload multiple images on firebase storage. ***but, dont forget to check the firebase rules***, I am adding rules below.

---

**firebase storage rules**

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```